# What is the defininition of the word Verhältnis in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This comes from Schopenhauer's Über die Weiber:

> Sonach hat die Natur das Weib, eben wie jedes andere ihrer Geschöpfe, mit den Waffen und Werkzeugen ausgerüstet, deren es zur Sicherung seines Daseyns bedarf, und auf die Zeit, da es ihrer bedarf; wobei sie denn auch mit ihrer gewöhnlichen Sparsamkeit verfahren ist. Wie nämlich die weibliche Ameise, nach der Begattung, die fortan überflüssigen, ja, für das **Brutverhältniß** gefährlichen Flügel verliert;

As far as I know the word "die Brut" means "the brood"/"the offspring" - correct me if I'm wrong.

Verhältnis seems to mean relationship. Can someone tell me what this word actually means in this context?

Comment: **Verhältnis** can also simply mean *condition*.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, *Brutverhältniß*—here still written with *ß*, but today written with *s*—means *circumstance* or *condition* of the breed. Nowadays, you would use the plural to express these meanings.

Side note: In English, the words *circumstances* and *conditions* both can be used with the prepositions *in* or *under*. In German, *Verhältnisse* usually occurs with *in*, whereas the synonym *Bedingungen* usually occurs with *unter*:

> Er ist *in* schlechten *Verhältnissen* aufgewachsen.
>
> Er ist *unter* schlechten *Bedingungen* aufwachsen.

Answer (score 0):

The passage was talking about how "females" aim for the survival of the fittest in reproduction.

The last sentence translates: "And the female ant, as a result of the "begetting," will lose a dangerous wing, which, from then on, will become superfluous for the breeding-relation."

Das Brutverhaltnis, or "breeding relation" is what humans would call sexual relations (except that it works slightly differently for ants).